# Error "could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity' while launching activity

Tags: android, android-emulator, robotium, android-support-library

What steps will reproduce the problem?
1. Create a dummy AUT android native app with one activity.
2. Create the test robotium project 
3. In the test project add "AndroidTestUtility.jar" file (not able to attach here) in libs folder along with robotium 3.6 jar file.
4. The "AndroidTestUtility.jar" handles the setup and tear down by itself.
5. Add similar code as below:

```
private static final String TARGET_PACKAGE_ID ="com.sap.esm.retail";
private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME2 ="com.sap.esm.retail.MobileRetailingActivity"; // First Activity


 public InitialTest() throws ClassNotFoundException {
            super(TARGET_PACKAGE_ID,LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME2);

 }
```

6. Add a sample test method that the robotium would execute.
7. Run the android junit test.
8. Error message  in logcat shown:

```
Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.getSupportFragment
```

1. Error message in IDE shown :
   java.lang.NullPointerException

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?

The test framework "AndroidTestUtility" is extended by the main class of the test robotium project.The expected output should have been the launch of the activity and the subsequent automated steps for it.
Actualt output is that the activity is launched but no automated steps (solo statements) are executed. The error message is shown in the attached screenshots.

What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?
Windows 7 64bit, Android ADT bundle, Robotium 3.6 (checked on 3.4.1 also), Target: Android API 15

Can anyone help me here ?

Thanks and Regards,

Abhishek

Comment: Post the whole logcat output for null pointer exception

Comment: Logcat file can be downloaded from: [link] (http://www.2shared.com/document/JvKoOJL5/Entirelog.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the robotium method that waits for a support fragment you need to have the android support v4 lib exported in one of the APKs, typically this would be in the AUT because it is the part actually using it (showing the fragment) then your robotium project will be able to use those instances of the class.

So to fix this, include android-support-v4.jar in either your test project or application projects lib folder.